# Create a database and entity model based on user input

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic

Currently I'm adjusting a system that works with Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

For the new part the key users need to add, change and remove entities that the normal users can use. Before I make a system that saves objects with names and with attributes I wanted to look if it is possible to create the database dynamically with the entities that the key users are giving (through a simplified entity designer).

I've search a little bit but on the internet but didn't find something quite like this. Maybe someone here knows something to push me in the right direction?

Comment: Oh, that's a nasty problem... Maybe you can save the entity attributes as an XML document. What are your requirements for querying?

Comment: Yeah, it really is a nasty problem.
Especially because we have to create dynamic overview pages with filters on the entities attribute's that the key users will define. Next to that there will be all lot of data in all the entities and they have to link to each other. 

Its almost like I've got to create a web based database designer for dummies.

Comment: Interesting question. My gut says that you won't be able to do this with EF (given that if I understand your requirements you'd have to recompile your data model on the fly), but I'm curious to see what people come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are best off by really defining tables, columns, indexes and foreign keys dynamically. If you were to use a "database of databases" schema with entities and attributes you would be unable to effectively index the database. Queries become extraordinarily slow and nasty.

You can query and change the database schema using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO). I have used them multiple times. They work and are quite nice to work with.

I'm not convinced that Entity Framework brings much to the table here. EF is good for expressing queries and DML on a static schema. If you were to use a dynamic schema you lose most of the benefits. Of course, some benefits remain such as entity key management and being able to use Entity SQL instead of T-SQL. On the downside you have to create all EF metadata at runtime (probably generate EDMX files or dynamic assemblies).

I think it is not worth it. I'd strongly consider building a database schema at runtime and executing queries against it using dynamically built T-SQL. It is much easier to do this than work against the system with EF.

In that sense you are back to `DataTables` and `GridViews` which was considered good style even 5 years ago. It's probably not too bad.

Comment: I was afraid that SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) would be the answer. But then you got a project with Entity Framework for the 'old' part and dynamic T-SQL for the part we're going to make now. I hope someone knows another way.

Comment: @Christiaan If the requirements change is this big, you may want to consider a whole new application (obviously not knowing exactly what the scope of your original application is). I'm inclined to agree with this answer; however suitable EF may have been for your original project, it isn't likely to fit with this new requirement.